# How to run Consul on docker with initial key-value pair data?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul

I am trying to spin a Consul server on docker container and use it as config server for my SpringBoot cloud application. For that I want to have some pre-configured data(Key-Value pairs) in Consul.

My current config in docker-compose.yml is:

```
  consul:
    image: "progrium/consul:latest"
    container_name: "consul"
    ports:
      - '9330:8300'
      - '9400:8400'
      - '9500:8500'
      - '9600:53'
    command: "-server -bootstrap -ui-dir /ui"
```

Is there a way to pre-populate key-value pairs?

Comment: I'd say the cli https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/kv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Compose

Compose doesn't have "tasks" as built in concept, but you can set them up with multiple compose files in a project. A `docker-compose-init.yml` could define the tasks, rather than long running services but you need to manage orchestration yourself. I've put an [example on my consul demo](https://github.com/deployable/docker-consul).

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose -f docker-compose-init.yml run consul_init
```

### Image Build

You can add image build `RUN` steps to add the data. The complication here is running the server the same way you normally would, but in the background, and adding the data all in the one `RUN` step.

```
FROM progrium/consul:latest
RUN set -uex; \
    consul agent -server --bootstrap -data-dir /consul/data & \ 
    let "timeout = $(date +%s) + 15"; \
    while ! curl -f -s http://localhost:8500/v1/status/leader | grep "[0-9]:[0-9]"; do\
      if [ $(date +%s) -gt $timeout ]; then echo "timeout"; exit 1; fi; \
      sleep 1; \
    done; \
    consul kv put somekey somevalue;
```

### Image Startup

Some databases add a script to the image to populate data at startup. This is normally so users can control setup via environment variables injected at run time, like [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)/[postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)/[mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/).

```
FROM progrium/consul:latest
ENTRYPOINT my-entrypoint.sh
```

Then your script starts the server, sets up the data, and then at the end continues on as the image would have before.

Answer (score 4):

Here a very similar approach but maybe simpler and it works. Does not require compose, just Docker and all is done in the image.

This directory structure:

```
bootstrap/values.json
bootstrap/start.sh
bootstrap/init.sh
Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM consul

RUN mkdir /tmp/bootstrap

COPY bootstrap/* /tmp/bootstrap/
RUN chmod 755 /tmp/bootstrap/*
RUN dos2unix /tmp/bootstrap/*

CMD /tmp/bootstrap/start.sh
```

**bootstrap/start.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

/tmp/bootstrap/init.sh &

consul agent -dev -client=0.0.0.0
```

**bootstrap/init.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "bootstrap values - wait until port is available"

while ! nc -z localhost 8500; do   
  sleep 1
done

echo "executing consul kv command"

consul kv import @/tmp/bootstrap/values.json
```

**bootstrap/values.json**

```
[
    {
            "key": "config/",
            "flags": 0,
            "value": ""
    },
    {
            "key": "config/yoursoftware/",
            "flags": 0,
            "value": ""
    },
]
```

The main challenge is that RUN can not process background tasks and CMD is the only main executable which must run at the end. So background processes can be started in via CMD, which uses here a shell script (start.sh). In that script the ampersand symbol gives under linux a way to start a process and throw it to background. It will execute the init.sh. In that it must now wait until the port is ready and then it can use the import.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the accepted solution to work for me. I'm guessing this is because the stub consul that it starts up during build time is somehow overwritten during run time.

Using the accepted answer as a jumping-off point, I instead added a loader script that starts up every time the container starts. The `Dockerfile` below adds a "shim" to the Consul entrypoint script (see `RUN sed`).

To use this:

- Add the `Dockerfile` below
- Add an `init_kv/` directory next to the `Dockerfile`
- Add json files to the `init_kv/` directory, such as `yourkey.json`

  - Use the key as the name of the json file
  - In this example, the key is `yourkey`
- Run `docker build`/`docker run`/`docker-compose up`, etc

Of note:

- The loader script runs *every time* the container starts
- The loader script will refuse to load a key if it already exists

  - In the example, if `yourkey` already exists, it will not be reloaded

`Dockerfile`

```
# pull official base image
FROM consul

# key-value shim loader
# you can override this loader using an empty docker volume:
ENV INIT_CONSUL_KV_DIR=/var/local/init_consul_kv.d
RUN mkdir -p $INIT_CONSUL_KV_DIR
COPY kv_loader.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN sed -ie 's|^\(set .*\)|\1\n/usr/local/bin/kv_loader.sh \&|' /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
COPY init_kv/ $INIT_CONSUL_KV_DIR/
```

`kv_loader.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# wait until consul is up
# then inject all key/value files as found in the init directory
set -ue

let "timeout = $(date +%s) + 15"

echo "kv_loader waiting for consul"
while ! curl -f -s http://localhost:8500/v1/status/leader | grep "[0-9]:[0-9]"; do
  if [ $(date +%s) -gt $timeout ]; then echo "kv_loader timeout"; exit 1; fi
  sleep 1
  echo "kv_loader still waiting"
done

echo "kv_loader get/put from $INIT_CONSUL_KV_DIR"
cd $INIT_CONSUL_KV_DIR
for json_file in $(ls *.json); do
  key=$(echo $json_file | sed -e 's/.json$//')
  echo "kv_loader loading $key from $json_file"
  consul kv get $key >/dev/null && echo "kv_loader $key already loaded" || consul kv put $key @$json_file
done
```

Comment: You can remove the `kv get` operation prior to the put by using `-cas` with `-modify-index=0`.

`consul kv put -cas -modify-index=0 new_key new_value` for an existing key would cuase Consul to return "Error! Did not write to new_key: CAS performed with index=0 and key already exists."

Comment: @BlakeCovarrubias thanks for your addendum! I tried out this approach, however I could not find a good mechanism to use that in `sh` to give a positive confirmation that the key exists. Using `consul kv put -cas -modify-index=0 $key @$json_file || echo "failure code: $?"`, the error code is a generic `1`, so it could be due to any consul error. That also outputs a scary-looking "Error! Did not write" message, even though the "failure" is actually desired. If there's a cleaner way to positively confirm the key exists, I'll definitely give that a shot as well.