# how to initial setup consul with defined key/value

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul

I have setup docker config using docker compose.

this is part of docker compose file

```
version: '3'
networks:
  pm:
services:
  consul:
    container_name: consul
    image: consul:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8300:8300
      - 8301:8301
      - 8302:8302
      - 8400:8400
      - 8500:8500
      - 8600:8600
    environment:
      CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG: >-
        {
          "bootstrap": true,
          "server": true,
          "node_name": "consul1",
          "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
          "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
          "bootstrap_expect": 1,
          "ui": true,
          "addresses" : {
            "http" : "0.0.0.0"
          },
          "ports": {
            "http": 8500
          },
          "log_level": "DEBUG",
          "connect" : {
            "enabled" : true
          }
        }
    volumes:
      - ./data:/consul/data
    command: agent -server -bind 0.0.0.0 -client 0.0.0.0 -bootstrap-expect=1
```

Then set the key value via browser

I would like to add the key/value as initial at new environment, so that additional setup steps at browser could be avoided.

this is the configuration i export by using consul kv command:

```
# consul kv export config/
[
        {
                "key": "config/",      
                "flags": 0,
                "value": ""
        },
        {
                "key": "config/drug2/",
                "flags": 0,
                "value": ""
        },
        {
                "key": "config/drug2/data",
                "flags": 0,
                "value": "e30="
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge Docker Compose does not have a way to run a custom command/script after the containers have started.

As a workaround you could write a shell script which executes `docker-compose up` and then either runs `consul kv import` or a `curl` command against Consul's [Transaction](https://www.consul.io/api/txn.html) API to add the data you're trying to load.

Comment: so i can use consul kv import to import the config that i saw at [export] ? same json structure? using cmd?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That data can also be used during the import process.

Comment: This is duplicated and a good working solution without docker-compose can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598002/how-to-run-consul-on-docker-with-initial-key-value-pair-data/71661406#71661406